# Trouble installing Cytoscape : App store not reachable

Tags: installation, cytoscape

I have troubles installing Cytoscape. 
All started from the common "The JVM could not be started" error. Hence, I downloaded the debugging "Windows.bat" script that yielded the following results :

### Cytoscape System Requirements Checker for Windows

Target Cytoscape version: 3.7.2

Your Windows version is:

Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.18362.720]

Java is installed

Your system is 64 bit

Your JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14

Your Java version is at least version 8 as required

Your Java version is no higher than version 8 as required

Your Java is 64 bit as recommended

Problem: The "app" store at apps.cytoscape.org is not reachable with a timeout of 30000ms

### Summary

Your system has some issues.
Please fix those and re-run this script again:
- App store at apps.cytoscape.org is not reachable

Then, it tries to determine the itinerary but stops around the 17-18 step.

Thanks a lot for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have a different problem...  Cytoscape 3.7.2 is only supported on Java 8, and you have Java 14 installed.  Cytoscape 3.8 (release is imminent) will support Java 11, but not Java 14.  Getting the correct Java installed should allow you to run Cytoscape.  The app store problem might be transitory.  I would suggest trying Cytoscape 3.8 before going too far out of your way to try to debug this.  We intend to release Cytoscape 3.8 today or tomorrow...

-- scooter